# Characterizing the dual space of the linear space of the signed measures generated by a given set of measures.

Tags: measure-theory, dual-spaces, measurable-functions, signed-measures

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space, $\varphi,\psi_{1},\ldots,\psi_{p}$ be real valued measurable functions on  $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and the set  $\mathcal{M}$ of all non-negative measures on the measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that each function $\varphi,\psi_{1},\ldots,\psi_{p}$ is $\mu$-integrable for all $\mu\in \mathcal{M}$.

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be be the linear space (over $\mathbb{R}$) of signed measures generated by $\mathcal{M}$.

**The question:** *What is the dual space of $\mathcal{X}$? Actually I need a characterization of the dual space.*

**Remark:** In this  [link](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=gabzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=linear%20space%20of%20signed%20measures%20generated%20by&source=bl&ots=bIlLrOZz3x&sig=C1hYDPoULYMlgE3yw6-8EBNW_fs&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi99Z3ehZXZAhXEp1kKHdohCmUQ6AEIUDAE#v=onepage&q=linear%20space%20of%20signed%20measures%20generated%20by&f=false) it is implied that the dual space of $\mathcal{X}$ is
$$\mathcal{X}'=\left\{f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\:|\: f \mbox{ is linear combinations of the functions }\varphi,\psi_{1},\ldots,\psi_{p}\right\}.$$
My intention is to show this last through an isometry.

**My attempt:**  We called
$$\mathcal{R}:=\left\{f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\:|\: f \mbox{ is linear combinations of the functions }\varphi,\psi_{1},\ldots,\psi_{p}\right\}.$$

Then we consider the following function
$$
\begin{array}{rclrcl}
\Phi:\mathcal{R} &\longrightarrow & \mathcal{X}' \\
f=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\alpha_{i}f_{i} & \longmapsto & \Phi f:&\mathcal{X} &\longrightarrow &\mathbb{R} \\
& & &\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\beta_{j}\mu_{j} &\longmapsto & \int_{\Omega} f(\xi) \mu(d\xi).
\end{array}
$$
I showed that $\Phi$ is well defined, it is linear and injective, **the problem is that I have failed to demonstrate the surjectivity**, this situation has led me to doubt whether this actually makes some sense.